# Black-Scholes vs Blacks model. Which one to use with SABR?

Tags: options, option-pricing, sabr

Say I want to compute a call price for a given set of SABR parameters.

I use Hagans approximation and compute $\sigma_B$. The rate is not zero. Should I then compute the option price using

- Blacks formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_model)
- or Black-Scholes formula? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black–Scholes_model)

Does it matter whether the asset is a forward or not?

Comment: I am 99% sure you have to use the first one. SABR IV is after all obtained by Black's formula. But I am actually not sure.